# Heuristic for Rubik's cube

Tags: search, artificial-intelligence, computer-science

I am trying to understand Pattern Databases for designing heuristics. I am reading Richard E. Korf's book *Heuristic Search*. One of its paragraphs says

> The obvious heuristic for Rubik's Cube is a three dimensional version of the Manhattan distance. For each cubie, compute the minimum number of moves required to correctly position and orient it, and sum these values over all cubies.Unfortunately, to be admissible, this value has to be divided by 8, since every twist moves 8 cubies. A better heuristic is to take the maximum of the sum of Manhattan distances of the corner cubies, divided by four, and the maximum of the sum of edge cubies divided by 4. The expected value of the Manhattan distance of the edge cubies is 22/4=5.5, while the corresponding values for the corner cubies is 12.333/4 that's approximately equal to 3.08 partly because there are 12 edge cubies, but only eight corner cubes.

My question is why taking the maximum of the sum of Manhattan distances for corner cubies divided by four and the maximum of the sum of Manhattan distances for edge cubies divided by four is better heuristic than taking the sum of Manhattan distances divided by eight?

Besides, how do they get the expected values of 5.5 and 3.08?

Comment: I believe this is *technically* on-topic here, but you might have better luck with your question on [cs.stackexchange.com](http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: [Also posted on CS.SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/55660/755).
Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: @alexw, thanks for trying to help s_123, however, in the future, if you're going to suggest another site, please remind people not to cross-post -- you can suggest they delete their question on one site before posting on another.  This will help them have a better experience.  Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed you voted to close on CS.SE.  Why not vote to close here instead?  SO is getting monstrously large as it is, and I believe sites like CS.SE were created precisely to provide a more specific venue for certain types of questions (like algorithm design).

Answer (score 2):

It is better in this sense that it is closer to true value of the distance, as considering movement of corner/edge cubicles has smaller amount of errors induced. By induced error I mean calculating some distance even though you already calulated different one, which would modify your cube, thus the current computation carries on error, and so is the next one, and next one ... in general - the smalelr number of (nearly) independent elements you can find, which still guarantee heuristics to be admissable is prefered, as heuristic like this (simple summation) assumes **independence** of each movement, which is simply not true in rubics cube. Thus the smaller number of violations of the independences - the more reliable the heuristics.